# Can't start NodeJS HTTPS server. v0.10.23

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate

Some time ago I tried pretty much the same code on previous version of nodejs and it worked (suppose we have *router* already)

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require("fs");
var crypto = require("crypto");

var private_key = fs.readFileSync("cert/domainname.key").toString();
var cert = fs.readFileSync("cert/domainname.crt").toString();
var options = crypto.createCredentials({
  key: private_key,
  cert: cert
});

var server = https.createServer(options, router);
server.listen(8080);
```

I got error **Missing PFX or certificate + private key.** Why is that? I passed both private key and certtificate.

Comment: Is that the correct relative path? Do you have permissions to read the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `crypto.createCredentials()` or `.toString()` the file contents:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/domainname.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/domainname.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, router):
```

[`https.createServer()`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) expects an `options` `Object`, with either a `pfx` or `key` and `cert`, rather than a [*credentials* object](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcredentials_details) created by `crypto.createCredentials()`.

And using `.toString()` on the `Buffer`s from `readFileSync()` will attempt to treat the binary as UTF-8 and convert to a UTF-16 `String`, which may actually cause data loss.

---

Side note: Unlike `require()`, `fs` paths like `'cert/domainname.key'` will be relative to the [current working directory](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd). To treat them as relative to the current module file, you can combine them with [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

```
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/domainname.key')
```

Comment: Right, thanks, first part of the answer is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

See an example of using https with express here: https://github.com/steinfletcher/https-expressjs-example/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, but I would mention express in question if needed.